# Given: $f(x)=5/(x+4)$ and $g(x)= -1/(7-x),$ find $h(x)=(fg)(-3)?$

Tags: calculus

Given: $f(x)=5/(x+4)$ and $g(x)= -1/(7-x)$, find $h(x)=(fg)(-3)$?

The answer is : $-1/2$ correct?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Are you being asked to multiply or _compose_ the functions $ \ f \ $ and $ \ g \ $ ?  If you are multiplying, then yes; if you are composing them, you'll get something rather different...

Comment: All right, I see by picking up the trail of your earlier posts that this _is_ intended to be function multiplication.  Please be aware that this is not considered the best way to notate that:  $ \ h(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) \ $ would be unambiguous.  Writing $ \ (fg)(x) \ $ is often used to represent $ \ f \circ g(x) \ = \ f(g(x)) \ . $

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, since:
$$
(fg)(-3) = f(-3) \cdot g(-3) = \dfrac{5}{-3+4} \cdot \dfrac{-1}{7-(-3)} = 5 \cdot \dfrac{-1}{10} = \dfrac{-1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

When x = -3, f(x) = 5 and g(x) = -1/10 so (fg)(-3) = 5 X -1/10 = -5/10 - -1/2.  So you are correct.

Comment: This is correct, but very difficult to read given the formatting. it really helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards